# Laravel 5.6.26 Error- Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

FYI,

I have gone through several web links and found solutions like changing/adding to **composer.json** file

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12" 
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-beta.3" 
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.2"
```

**app.php** config file with LaravelServiceProvider/JWTAuthServiceProvider

```
providers => [
---
        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,

        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
---
]
aliases => [
-----
'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
-----
]
```

And

```
composer update --no-scripts
composer update
```

When publishing:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Error message below.

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

composer update output below

```
$composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-beta.3 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[1.0.0-beta.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-beta.3 requires illuminate/auth 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[5.1.x-dev].

    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev].
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, since you are using Laravel 5.6 you need to have this version (`1.0.0-rc.2` as the newest stable version), then there is **no need to implicitly type hint the service provider** or the alias for its facade! the library itself shall do so for you. So please remove what you've added to `$providers` & `$aliases` arrays.

Then make sure to run:

`composer dump-autoload -o`

and

`php artisan clear-compiled`

If you are running less than 5.6 for Laravel, let me know

Answer (score 14):

There is some problem while downloading the package
Try running

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

and in your config/app.php make providers as

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

Also provide the Aliases as:

```
'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
```

After all the above steps publish your vendor:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

And generate auth secret : `php artisan jwt:secret`

Answer (score 8):

Add library to composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-beta.3"
    ...
 },
```

Run this command in console:
composer update

Add provider in config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
    ...
],
```

Add aliases in the same file `config/app.php':

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
    'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
    ...
],
```

And then run command in console:
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
next run:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

Comment: Thanks, I have clearly mentioned the various options(including your answer) I have tried.

Comment: check this link it will help , https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1038

Comment: you can check that link fully and notice my question as it includes all of them.

Comment: Then needs to check installation doc, something is missing while installing.
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/#install-via-composer

Comment: Checked this one too. no luck :-(

Answer (score 7):

i've had this problem for a while and none these answers worked for me. after struggling with problem i found a solution.

try installing jwt-auth from command below if you use **laravel above 5.5** :

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

then you will have no problem anymore

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still return error, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500793/laravel-class-tymon-jwtauth-providers-jwtauthserviceprovider-not-found

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still return error, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500793/laravel-class-tymon-jwtauth-providers-jwtauthserviceprovider-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error after upgrading to Laravel 6 and jwt-auth 1.0. I had finished the upgrade on my local machine and gotten everything working by following the installation instructions for jwt-auth 1.0 (and ignoring the part for Laravel 5.4 and below).

The error came when I tried to deploy to my test environment. `composer install` and `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"` both failed with the error `Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found` (that's the old provider from jwt-auth 0.5).

The key for me was to delete this file: `.../bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Apparently, this file can also be an issue, but it wasn't present for me: `.../bootstrap/cache/services.php`.

Answer (score 0):

changed Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' to Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class

run: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code, I hope this is helpful:

In `providers` => `[Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,],`

To publish the configuration file in Laravel, you need to run following line of code :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have JWT yet!

Execute:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

Then:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```